# How many distinct roots $ax^5+bx^3+cx+d$ has

Tags: functions, polynomials

> $a,b,c>0$
>
> How many distinct roots  $ax^5+bx^3+cx+d=0$ has?

question doesnt clarify which kind of root it has. and I dont understand why the question didnt say 'may has' . because by fundemantal theorem of algebra it can have 5,3 or 1 real root right?

secondly I tried to differentiate and subtitute $x^2=p$ which gives $5ap^2+3bp+c=0$ but how can I know either $9b^2-20c>0 $ or not

Comment: Over what domain are you looking for roots? The answer could be very different over $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: it should be $\Bbb R$

Comment: Exactly one real root with the opposite sign of $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be this polynomial. Then $f'(x) = 5ax^4 + 3bx^2+c>0$ for any $x$ because all of the coefficients are $>0$ and $x^2,x^4 \ge 0$. So, $f$ is strictly increasing everywhere. With $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$, we conclude that $f(x) = 0$ has a unique real solution.

This of course doesn't mean that $f(x) = 0$ has no complex solutions (it has two).

Comment: Another way to say this is that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so $f(x)=0$ has the unique solution $x=f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Thanks.  It is irrelavant but what can we say about its complex root at f(x) =0